# Combine a list of dataframes with different size into a dataframe with one row per dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list of 2 dataframes in R and want to combine them to one dataframe in R. My list of data frames look like:

```
df1 <- data.frame(d=c(0,1,2),n=c(5,5,5),i=c(2,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(d=c(0,1,2,3),n=c(5,5,5,5),i=c(2,3,3,4))

list <- list(df1,df2)
```

How can I take the list of dataframes and transform it so that I have one data.frame that looks like this:

```
new_df <- data.frame(d=c(0;1;2,0;1;2;3),n=c(5;5;5,5;5;5;5),i=c(2;3;3,2;3;3;4))
```

Where the columns of each dataframe in the list of dataframes are transformed to be separated by a semicolon in the new dataframe? Such that the new dataframe would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = 
  lapply(list, \(df) lapply(df, paste, collapse = ";")) |>
  lapply(as.data.frame) |>
  do.call(what = rbind)
result
#         d       n       i
# 1   0;1;2   5;5;5   2;3;3
# 2 0;1;2;3 5;5;5;5 2;3;3;4
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
df1 <- data.frame(d=c(0,1,2),n=c(5,5,5),i=c(2,3,3))
df2 <- data.frame(d=c(0,1,2,3),n=c(5,5,5,5),i=c(2,3,3,4))
list1 <- list(df1,df2)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list1 %>%  
  map(~summarise(.x, across(everything(), ~paste(.x, collapse = ";")))) %>% 
  bind_rows()

#>         d       n       i
#> 1   0;1;2   5;5;5   2;3;3
#> 2 0;1;2;3 5;5;5;5 2;3;3;4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>